# building openapi-generate produces a jar file that doesn't work

Tags: openapi-generator

After building the openapi-generator on Linux, using the resulting jar file produces the following error:

_ generating python openapi-client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "str" is null
at java.base/java.lang.String.concat(String.java:2766)
at org.openapitools.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:48)
at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.fromFile(CodegenConfigurator.java:94)
at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.Generate.execute(Generate.java:272)
at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.OpenApiGeneratorCommand.run(OpenApiGeneratorCommand.java:32)
at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator.main(OpenAPIGenerator.java:66)

Other developers on my team are able to build it without this problem, so I'm sure it has to do with my environment.  It's not clear what that problem is though.  Does anyone have a suggestion on what I can change to fix this problem?

Comment: What command & arguments do you use to run the JAR?

Comment: generate -g python --global-property=apiTests=false,modelTests=false -o <dir>/generated -c <dir>/clientConfig.yaml -i <dir>/docs/api/spec/current.yaml   -- BTW, I don't get this error with .jar files built by other developers (we all use the same build for the application).  It's just my build of the .jar file that causes this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11276

Comment: well, the other developers that are working have java 14.0.2.  I'm using 17.0.1.  So, that could be it

Comment: nope, I tried java 14.0.2 with the same result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a bug introduced into the openapi github repository: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11276#issuecomment-1012171502

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).